Pagination is not working properly using React-Router DOM
I am trying to implement pagination for components named "Shop", Contact and Cart using react-router-dom.
To store the URL paths I have used an array.
A state variable is used as an array index to retrive specific paths.
useRef is used to store specific path and to change it whenever "next" or "prev" button is clicked.
Here whenever the Next or Prev is clicked, the components are displayed first and then the state variable is updated.
Thus when we click "Prev" after clicking "Next" the next component is displayed. After that if we again click the "Prev" then the previous component is displayed.
Please provide a solution or an alternative way to implement the same.
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./bottombar.css";

const Bottombar = () => {
  const pathArray = ["shop","contact","cart"]
  const [array_index, setArrayIndex] = useState(0);
  const path = useRef("");
  const handleNext =() =>{
    if(array_index== pathArray.length-1)
      {
        setArrayIndex(0)
      }
      else{
        setArrayIndex(prev => prev+1)
      }
  }
  const handlePrev =() =>{
    if(array_index== 0)
      {
        setArrayIndex(pathArray.length-1)
      }
      else{
        setArrayIndex(prev => prev-1)
      }
  }
  path.current= pathArray[array_index];

  return (
    <div className="bottombar">
      <div className="links">
        <Link to={"/"+path.current} onClick={handlePrev}>Previous</Link>
        <Link to={"/"+path.current} onClick={handleNext}>Next</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Bottombar


Your component will get reload when a link is clicked, so your state is not even saved.

No need for state nor Ref.
By just having your path array, you can determine what link should be added on your links for prev and next when the component is loading. use can listen from the pathname (useHistory or usePathname whatever available) and match it with your array.


This is caused as the component is first loaded and then the link is updated after the handleNext and handlePrev functions are called. To avoid this, we can keep track of the next and prev link at any point of time with the help of variables nextPath and prevPath. These keep the links for the next and prev pages and append it to the link call when the Next and Previous are clicked.
Also there is some improvement in the check for array index to make sure it doesn't go out of bound.
Here's the code :
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { useRef, useState } from "react";
    import "./bottombar.css";
      const Bottombar = () => {
      const pathArray = ["shop","contact","cart"]
      const [array_index, setArrayIndex] = useState(0);
      const path = useRef("");
      const handleNext = () => {setArrayIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex + 1) % pathArray.length);
  };
      const handlePrev = () => {setArrayIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex - 1 + pathArray.length) % pathArray.length);
}
      const nextPath = pathArray[(arrayIndex + 1) % pathArray.length];
      const prevPath = pathArray[(arrayIndex - 1 + pathArray.length) % pathArray.length];

      return (
        <div className="bottombar">
          <div className="links">
            <Link to={"/"+prevPath} onClick={handlePrev}>Previous</Link>
            <Link to={"/"+nextPath} onClick={handleNext}>Next</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Bottombar;


Don't duplicate React-Router route matching logic and state, let the URL path be the source of truth and just compute what the next and previous target paths should be based on the current path value.
Basic Example:
import { Link, useLocation, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

const pathArray = ["shop", "contact", "cart"];

const Bottombar = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const match = matchPath("/:path", pathname);
  const index = pathArray.findIndex((path) => path === match?.params.path);
  const nextIndex = (index + 1) % pathArray.length;
  const prevIndex = index - 1 < 0 ? pathArray.length - 1 : index - 1;

  return (
    <div className="bottombar">
      <div className="links">
        <Link to={"/" + pathArray[prevIndex]}>Previous</Link>
        <Link to={"/" + pathArray[nextIndex]}>Next</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

